# Consuming result returned from a form post to a web service

Tags: javascript, html, xml, web-services, forms

i am calling a web service in this way:

```
    <form id="test"  method="post"  action="Services/AccessDetails.asmx/getTestData">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

and when i submit the button i get the result back in an XML format into a blank page but what i want is to read XML data and consume them in the same page which i placed the above code
using javascript (not using helper library like jquery)  so my page can be as light as possible

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to use jQuery for this, something like this should work:

markup:

```
<form id="testform"  method="post">
  <a href="javascript:;" id="btnSubmit">Submit</a>
</form>
```

javascript:

```
$(function(){
  $('#btnSubmit').click(function(e){
    $.post('Services/AccessDetails.asmx/getTestData',
           $("#testform").serialize(), 
           function(data){ /* Code to handle return from the server */;
                           alert("Data Loaded: " + data); }
    );
  });
});
```